# How do you clear a list in jQuery, i.e. delete all items in a list with one button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list, button

My code to delete a single task item works correctly, but the code to delete all the task items in one click is not working. Is there a simple way to delete everything or reset the list?

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/hufflepuff_hamlet/r9uogxwL/2/

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeAll()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> Clear All Tasks</span></button>
```

```
 //Clear Completed Task 
 
 $(".completed").on("click",'.btn-danger',function(){  
   $(this).parent("li").remove();
   
 })

 //Clear all Tasks in List
 
function removeAll(){
    document.getElementById(".uncompleted").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Add an id to your unordered list and then use $("#ul_id").empty()

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not at an external site. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable similar to codepen.

Comment: I don't see the "Clear all tasks" button in your codepen.

Comment: `uncompleted` is not an ID, it's a class. Use `document.querySelector(".uncompleted").innerHTML`

Comment: Sorry, I added the fiddle link with the correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all li items inside ul, you can do

```js
$('.uncompleted > li').remove();
```

Or you can use `empty` to empty the list

```js
$('.uncompleted').empty();
```

`innerHTML = ""` should have also worked, but you have an issue with selecting the element

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("uncompleted")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

Use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: Won't setting the inner HTML to an empty string have the same effect?

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. It works with the Remove buttons already existing, but when I am trying to apply this code specifically to the Clear All Tasks button, ,it doesn't work. I tried using a simple <button id="removeAll">Clear All Tasks</button> instead, but also not working. I guess I need to understand how to start off the function to apply to this button, and then add the code you provided.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks so much for your help.